# Displaying info from parent in entity field in form

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Scenario**

As part of a form to create an instance of ClassC, I want to select the parent ClassB by its ID.

This is no problem, and can be done as such:

```
->add('classB_id', 'entity', [
      'class' => 'NodeBundle:ClassB',
      'choice_label' => 'name'
])
```

Now, ClassB has a ClassA parent, and instead of just displaying the `name` of ClassB, I want to display `ClassB.name (ClassA.name)`, so it creates options in the select such as

```
<option value="4">SomeClassB (ParentClassA)</option>
```

This is because I might have ClassB instances with the same name, but belonging to different instances of ClassA.

**What I have so far**

```
->add('classB_id', 'entity', [
    'class' => 'NodeBundle:ClassB',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->leftJoin('NodeBundle:ClassA', 'a', 'WITH', 'b.classA_id = a.id')
            ->orderBy('p.classA_id', 'ASC');
    }
])
```

**Question**

How can I edit the `choice_label` option to display it in a format including information from the parent ClassA?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution by myself, although I'm VERY open to improvements, as it smells quite bad.

```
'choice_label' => function($classB) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('NodeBundle:ClassA');
    return $classB->getName() . ' - ' . $em->findOneBy(['id' => $classB->getClassAId()])->getName();
}
```

This fetches the parent instance of ClassA and attaches its name to the option label. But the reason it smells bad is because it does a database query for every option.

In my particular case, it's not that big of a deal, because

1. There are very few options in the list
2. It's only used by administrators, of which there is only one - me

For any other case, I'd say this is a bad way to do it, which is why I'm very open to new suggestions.